# Socket Programming HTTP, socket gets closed on its own and recv() return 0 when delayed

Tags: c, sockets, http

I am a newbie to socket programming, I got introduces to TCP programming from Lewis Van Winkle - Hands-On Network Programming with C.And this is my first question, please point them out if any.
For POST REQUEST FROM Either Signup or Login page, the Socket gets closed on its own.
And sometimes even for GET request, after some delay the recv() function returns 0 and doest send any data;
A little help or nudge in the right direction will help
My Code is as follows:-

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include<io.h>
#include <process.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#else
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#endif
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define ISVALIDSOCKET(s) ((s) != INVALID_SOCKET)
#define CLOSESOCKET(s) closesocket(s)
#define GETSOCKETERRNO() (WSAGetLastError())
#else
#define ISVALIDSOCKET(s) ((s) >= 0)
#define CLOSESOCKET(s) close(s)
#define SOCKET int
#define GETSOCKETERRNO() (errno)
#endif


#if defined(_WIN32) 
#else 
#define mkdir(s) mkdir(s,0666)
#endif



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ReadFrom(char uri[], char buffer[],SOCKET c1){

        sprintf(buffer, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
    send(c1, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    sprintf(buffer, "Connection: close \r\n");
    send(c1, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    sprintf(buffer, "Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
    send(c1, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
printf("\ntillhere23\n");
    sprintf(buffer, "\r\n");
    printf("\ntillhere23\n");
    send(c1, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    char filename[30]="./public/";
    strcat(filename,uri);
    printf("\ntillhere23\n");
    strcat(filename,".html");
    FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"rb");
    printf("\ntillhere23 %s  %d %c \n",filename,fp,fp);
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    printf("\ntillhere23 %s\n",filename);
    size_t cl = ftell(fp);
    printf("\ntillhere23 %s\n",filename);
    rewind(fp);
    printf("\ntillhere23 %s\n",filename);
    printf("%s helo :: \n",buffer);
    int r = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp);
    while (r) {
        send(c1, buffer, r, 0);
        r = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
int main(){
    #if defined(_WIN32)
    WSADATA d;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &d)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize.\n");
        return 1;
    }
#endif


    printf("Configuring local address...\n");
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    struct addrinfo *bind_address;
    getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1","8080", &hints, &bind_address);

    printf("Creating socket...\n");
    SOCKET socket_listen;
    socket_listen = socket(bind_address->ai_family,
            bind_address->ai_socktype, bind_address->ai_protocol);

    if (!ISVALIDSOCKET(socket_listen)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Binding socket to local address...\n");
    if (bind(socket_listen,
                bind_address->ai_addr, bind_address->ai_addrlen)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "bind() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
        exit(1);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(bind_address);
    SOCKET Server=socket_listen;
    SOCKET c1=-1;
    struct sockaddr_storage client_address;
 socklen_t client_len = sizeof(client_address);

    while(1){
        printf("Listening...\n");
    if (listen(socket_listen, 10) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listen() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
        exit(1);
    }
        c1 = accept(socket_listen,
 (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,
    &client_len);
        printf("CAME BACK %d\n",c1);
    printf("CAME BACK2 :: %d\n",c1);
    char buffer[1024];
    char req[1024];
    printf("receiving starts now::\n");
        printf("STATUS OF RECV: %d",recv(c1,req,1024,0));
        printf("\nRCV:\n%s\n",req);
        /*for(int i=0;i<strlen(req);i++){
            printf("\ni::%d ,char: %c, num:%d\n",i,req[i],req[i]);

        }


        printf("\n ABOVE CONTAINS ALLREQuests IN ASCII\n");*/
    if(req[0]=='G' &&req[1]=='E'&& req[2]=='T')
{   printf("\nEntered GET\n");  

if(strstr(req,"username")==NULL){
if(strstr(req,"/Login.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nenetered login\n");
        ReadFrom("Login",buffer,c1);
        CLOSESOCKET(c1);
    }

    else if(strstr(req,"/Logout.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {   
        CLOSESOCKET(c1);
        CLOSESOCKET(Server);
        printf("closed");
        exit(0);
    }

    else if(strstr(req,"/Signup.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nenetered signup\n");
        ReadFrom("Signup",buffer,c1);
        CLOSESOCKET(c1);
        printf("WHY CLOSE");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("\nenetered index\n");
            ReadFrom("index",buffer,c1);
    }



}
else {
    printf("INSTEAD \n");
    if(strstr(req,"/Move.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nenetered Move\n");
        MainRead(0,buffer,c1,1,USERNAMEnum);
    }
    else if(strstr(req,"/Read.html?Category=")!=NULL)
    {char Category[20];
        char Patid[20];
        wordify(req,"Category=","?",Category);
        wordify(req,"Patid=","?",Patid);
        ReadFrom("Read",buffer,c1);

    }
    else if(strstr(req,"/Write.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nenetered write\n");
        char Category[20];
        char Patid[20];
        wordify(req,"Category=","?",Category);
        wordify(req,"Patid=","?",Patid);
        ReadFrom("Read",buffer,c1);

    }
    else if(strstr(req,"/New.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\nenetered New\n");

        MainRead(0,buffer,c1,4,USERNAMEnum);
    }
    else if(strstr(req,"/Logout.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {   
        CLOSESOCKET(c1);
        CLOSESOCKET(Server);
        printf("closed");
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
    MainRead(0,buffer,c1,0,USERNAMEnum);
    }   
    }


}
    else if(req[0]=='P' && req[1]=='O' && req[2]=='S' && req[3]=='T')
{printf("came here to POST:\n");
    if(strstr(req,"/table1.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL)
    {printf("came here to TABLE\n");

    printf("GOT::TABLE\n");
    wordify(req,"Sno=","&",User.doctor_name);
    StoI(User.doctor_name,&User.serialno);
    wordify(req,"username=","&",User.username); 
    wordify(req,"&pswd=","\b",User.password);
    if(Login(User)==0){
        //Code for error
    }
    else{
        ItoS(USERNAMEnum,Login(User));
    }
    MainRead(0,buffer,c1,0,USERNAMEnum);
    printf("LOL");

    }else if (strstr(req,"/Signup.html HTTP/1.1")!=NULL){
        printf("\nenetered SIgnup in POST\n");
    wordify(req,"Sno1=","&",User.doctor_name);
    StoI(User.doctor_name,&User.serialno);
    wordify(req,"&Name=","&",User.doctor_name);
    wordify(req,"&Phoneno=","&",User.username);
    StoI(User.username,&User.Phoneno);
    wordify(req,"&Hospitalname=","&",User.hostipal_name);
    wordify(req,"&State1=","&",User.state);
    wordify(req,"&username1=","&",User.username);
    wordify(req,"&pswd1=","\b",User.password);
    printf("THE NUMBER:: %u ul \n",User.serialno);
    Signup(User);

        ReadFrom("Login",buffer,c1);
        printf("Signup success\n"); 
        CLOSESOCKET(c1);
    }

}
/*  else{
        CLOSESOCKET(c1);
        CLOSESOCKET(Server);
        printf("closed");
        exit(0);
        }*/

    }

    return 1;

}
```

Comment: `recv` returning 0 usually means graceful socket closure performed by the remote peer. What is not clear to me is if before the closure you get the expected data.

Comment: after a passive delay, the socket closes when the client is sending data, but for Post request from, client it receives the expected data before closure

Comment: So what you experience is probably the expected closure. The server says _"I sent all the data you requested me. Have a nice day. PS: if you need more connections, open a new socket"_. It is something I didn't deal with for years, but if I'm not wrong the closure-behavior is something some way configurable from server side.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, But if you had noticed, the code posted here is the server code and I am not closing the Server_listen socket binded to port 80 at any point and I am using my browser as a client to access it. Still, the Server socket closes and I want to know this reason. Thank you for the effort put in

Comment: ALL the functions defined after the place where they are called, need a prototype just aft the `#include` statements.  Otherwise, the compiler outputs LOTS of warning and error messages.  In other words, the posted code does not compile!

Comment: regarding: `int r = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp);
    while (r) {
        send(c1, buffer, r, 0);
        r = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp);
    }`  this would be much better written as a `do { ... }while();` loop then the call to `fread()` would be in only one place rather than 2 places.  Or even better: `int r; while( (r = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp) ) > 0 ) {`  Note:  always check the returned value from `send()` as may need to call it in a loop, with a moving window on the data, until all the data is sent.  Note: `read()` and `fread()` return a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: regarding statements like: `printf("closed");`  1) always terminate the format string with '\n' so the data is immediately passed to the terminal. (or better, use `puts()`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'. suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  The compiler does not care, but us humans sure do.  2) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `printf("Listening...\n");
        if (listen(socket_listen, 10) < 0) 
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "listen() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
            exit(1);
        }`  the code only needs to call `listen()` once, not every time through the `while(1)` loop.  So the `listen()` code should be before the `while(1)` loop

Comment: the function: `recv()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert a 'reasonable' space: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, around C operators.

Comment: regarding: `struct sockaddr_storage client_address;`  This would be much better written as: `struct sockaddr_in client_address;`

Comment: regarding: `if (!ISVALIDSOCKET(socket_listen)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed. (%d)\n", GETSOCKETERRNO());
        exit(1);`  a socket value of 0 is actually valid.  A socket value of < 0 indicates an error occurred
    }`

Comment: regarding: `SOCKET Server=socket_listen;`  This results in a copy of the socket number.  Better to (for instance) called it `Server` all the way through the code, rather than changing the  name in mid stream

Comment: regarding: `c1 = accept(socket_listen, 
                    (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,
                    &client_len);`  The returned value from `accept()` needs to be checked (>= 0) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: why the two statements: ` printf("CAME BACK %d\n",c1);` and `printf("CAME BACK2 :: %d\n",c1);`  Much clearer to only have one of those statements

Comment: Suggest placing the client communications in a thread pool entry, so more than one client can be handled at a time

Comment: regarding: `printf("STATUS OF RECV: %d",recv(c1,req,1024,0));`  a `%d` does not handle a `ssize_t`  suggest using: `%ld`

Comment: regarding function: `ReadFrom()`  The signature says it returns an `int` value, but the function does not end with: `return value;` statement.  However, all the calls to this function do not check the returned value, so suggest the signature be: `void ReadFrom( char uri[], char buffer[], SOCKET c1 )`

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"rb");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);`  This can fail, so always check (!=-1) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `int r = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, fp);
    while (r) {`   this function can return 0 or EOF so if EOF is returned, the `while( r )` will enter the loop body, many many times and the loop body will be transmitting garbage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without a call to `setsockopt()` to make the socket reusable, the socket will close, usually after the first communication.

suggest:

```
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)
{
    perror( "setsockopt with SO_REUSEADDR failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```